# How to drop messages in console when using spark-submit?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

When I run `spark-submit` job with `scala`, I can see a lot of status messages in console.

But I would like to see only my prints. Can I put any parameter in order not to see these messages?

Comment: Accept the answer if it was satisfactory; do not leave the question open.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick for the most part. Put it inside the code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.WARN)
```

Or this in `conf/log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console
```